# Algebra: Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> **Problem**
>
> Let $V$ be a real inner product space and $U \subset V$. Show that $(U^\perp)^\perp=U$.

**Progress**

Clearly for $x\in U$ we have that $\langle x,v \rangle=0$ for all $v \in U^\perp$. This immediately yields that $x \in (U^\perp)^\perp$ and so $U \subset (U^\perp)^\perp$.

Taking $x \in (U^\perp)^\perp$, we have that $\langle x,v \rangle=0$ for all $v \in U^\perp$. Not sure how to move it on from here though; any assistance would be much appreciated. Regards.

Comment: The answers below assume $V$ is finite dimensional; which is ok, since that's what your question seems to be assuming.

Comment: Indeed it is false for e.g. an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $V$ with a proper dense subspace $W$. This is because the orthogonal complement of a subset in a Hilbert space is always closed, so we have that $W^{\perp\perp} = \overline{W}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already know that $U\subseteq U^{\perp\perp}$, it will suffice that these two spaces have the same dimension. Since 
$$\dim(U^{\perp\perp})=\dim(V)-\dim(U^\perp)=\dim(V)-\dim(V)+\dim(U)=\dim(U),$$ 
you are done.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim V = n$ and $\dim U = k$, then $\dim U^\perp = n-k$. Then argue using orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the orthogonal decomposition $V=U\oplus U^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the orthogonal decomposition $V=U\oplus U^\perp$ mentioned in another answer here, every vector $v\in V$ may be decomposed as $v=p+n$ with $p\in U$ and $n\in U^\perp$. Then
$$\begin{align}
v\in(U^\perp)^\perp&\iff\forall n'\in U^\perp\ \langle v,n'\rangle=0\\
&\iff\forall n'\in U^\perp\ \langle n+p,n'\rangle=0\\
&\iff\forall n'\in U^\perp\ \langle n,n'\rangle+\langle p,n'\rangle=0\\
&\iff\forall n'\in U^\perp\ \langle n,n'\rangle=0\\
&\iff n=\mathbf 0\\
&\iff v\in U
\end{align}$$
and so $(U^\perp)^\perp=U$.